# Find the same element in ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-selectors

The element:

```
var obj = $(this).parent().find('a');

// $(this) is a <UL> inside a <DIV>, but there can be multiple DIV>ULs on the page
```

Next I get some HTML with $.ajax().

This HTML is another page which contains the link parent and the link

Is there a way to find that link without hardcoding the selector?

---

can i somehow get the full selector path to `obj` ? Like

```
body > div#content > div:nth-child(4) > a
```

That way I can find the one from the ajax response based on this selector

Comment: can you please provide some scenario, so that the need can be understood easily.?

Comment: `obj.selector` would return the selector used, and in your case that would only return `a`, so no, without a proper selector, like an ID, there's no easy way to do that.

Comment: As far as I can tell you are trying to get the actual DOM position (showing inheritance) of the element in question in the form of a CSS selector. Short answer, not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `.parents()` of the link, you could gather the `id`s and `class`es and create a selector from that.
Something like:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(link.parents()).reverse().map(function (element) {
  if (element.id) return "#" + element.id;
  if (element.className) return "." + element.className.split(" ").join(".");
  return element.tagName.toLowerCase();
}).join(" ");
```

Although this would needs to be refined so the `parents` don't go up to HTML, but only the required element.